# @Mailsend in xpages button

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

In Client Notes programming there is an action button:

```
@MailSend(Destinatari;"";"";"Subject";"";"";IncludeDoclink])&
@Command([FileSave])&@Command([FileCloseWindow])
```

I want to make a similar action in my xpage application which works both in XPiNC and web.

My `sendto` field is a `DjTextarea` which can have multiple values.

I tried to create a `simple action` for my button from xpage: `Action: Send Mail`. In this way, can I embedded < the `IncludeDoclink` from Lotus Notes> in the body of the mail? Or I need to write a javascript for this action?

Thanks for your time!

UPDATE: following @Lothar suggestions, my `Save & Send` button has the following code lines:

```
if(frmDoc.isNewNote()){
    frmDoc.save();
}
var thisdoc = frmDoc.getDocument();
var tempdoc = database.createDocument();
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", thisdoc.getItemValue("txt_names"));
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "subject");
var tempbody:NotesRichtextItem = tempdoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
tempbody.appendText("This is my Mail, click on the doc link below to open the original doc:")
tempbody.addNewLine(2);
tempbody.appendDocLink(thisdoc);
tempdoc.send();
thisdoc.recycle();
tempbody.recycle();
tempdoc.recycle();
```

Where `frmDoc` is my doc datasource. I get an error like: `NotesRichTextItem.appendDocLink(lotus.domino.local.Document) null` - at the `appendDoclink` line. - the same error I noticed in the @Fredrik useful suggestion too.

Comment: @Lothar 's code does work for me - it creates an email with a valid link to frmDoc. I changed this line `var thisdoc = frmDoc.getDocument(true);` though: parameter `true` returns the document with the *new* values. This doesn't matter if document is new and get saved at the beginning of code but is important for existing documents. Without `true` thisdoc has still the old values. But I think it has nothing to do with your appendDocLink issue.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann : it seems to work, now. Happy me! Btw: How can I close the doc., after the send method? Is there any chance to send also the urlLink for opening the doc in browser? ( Currently, it opens in XPiNC )

Comment: @KnutHerrmann I use tempbody.appendText(context.getUrl().toString()) for the URL - the ugly part is that it opens it in the web browser of the NC, not in the browser where the app runs, for example: Chrome. I just need to find out how to close the current document, after saving it.

Comment: It should depend on current user "Location" settings. Choose your favorite Internet browser there and doc will be opened in selected browser.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Yes, I did change the settings from the NC. For the close method I use: facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://myserver/myview.xsp") - is not what I was looking for, but is an alternative, I guess.

Comment: Closing document in XPage/browser means usually to open XPage opened before. So, your redirect is fine.

Comment: Thanks again! I will accept Fredrik answer, even if Lothar step-by-step explanations help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the HTML email function that can be found in xSnippets when sending emails in xpages.

[XSnippet SSJS HTML Mime emails](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime)

or

[XSnippet email Bean](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter)

None of them as an function for attaching a doclink, but you could manually add an url to the document.

Another way is to create the email manually by creating a document is the database 
adding a richtextfield called body and a subject and a sendto field.
And adding a doclink to the Body field.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var My_DocLink_Doc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByUNID("UNID_of_Document")
doc.replaceItemValue("form", "Memo");
doc.replaceItemValue("sendTo", "the_emailadress");
doc.replaceItemValue("subject", "an email to you");
var RT:NotesRichTextItem=doc.createRichTextItem("Body")
RT.appendText("This is my Text")
RT.addNewLine()
RT.appendDocLink(My_DocLink_Doc)
doc.send();
```

Comment: Thanks. The My_DocLink_Doc should contain the UNID of the document? I get an error for this parameter.

Comment: It should contain a NotesDocument or NotesDatabase.

Comment: a NotesDocument meaning the currentDocument that is an XPage - which after saving it - it will display the UNID on the url link? Being a XPiNC and browser application, should I use instead the url link ?

Comment: You would need two links one for the web and one for XPiNC.

Comment: I tried your example, replacing the UNID_of_Document with an UNID of an already saved document. It displays an error at: RT.appendDocLink(My_DocLink_Doc), [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesRichTextItem.appendDocLink(lotus.domino.local.Document) null

Comment: NotesRichTextItem is that you variable ?
The error explains that this or the My_DocLink_Doc is empty

Comment: MFG Use this to get the doclink for the current document: My_DocLink_doc= document1.getDocument().getUniversalID(); not sure it it will work 100% for you as I am composing HTML emails to send.

Comment: As Fredrik indicated, `My_DocLink_Doc` should be a Document handle, not the UNID. In other words, `document1.getDocument()`, *not* `document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()`.

Comment: @TimTripcony thanks for your suggestion, still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

There's really not much to add to Fredrik's answer, but I'm afraid you might be looking at the wrong pieces of his solution. I just tested it myself, and it's working just fine, so here's the result, step-by-step:

my xpage is bound to a Notes form named **testMail** using a document datasource called **mailDoc**. It is built like this:
Control#1 is a textarea with a multiple separator set to a comma, so that I can enter multiple mail addresses separated by commas. The textarea is bound to a Notes field named **SendTo**:

```
<xp:inputTextarea
    value="#{mailDoc.SendTo}"
    id="sendTo1"
    multipleSeparator=",">
</xp:inputTextarea>
```

Control #2 is a simple EditBox control bound to a Notes field named **Subject**:

```
<xp:inputText
    value="#{mailDoc.Subject}"
    id="subject1">
</xp:inputText>
```

A button control labelled **Save & Send** first saves the current document if it is *New* (i.e. has never been saved before), then performs all the necessary steps to send a doclink for the currently opened doc (*button's onclick event*); in the following code I'm using these variables:
mailDoc = my datasource object;
thisdoc = the backend doc object that the datasource is bound to;
tempdoc = a temp backend doc object used to be sent via Notes mail:

```
if(mailDoc.isNewNote()){
    mailDoc.save();
}
var thisdoc = mailDoc.getDocument();
var tempdoc = database.createDocument();
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", thisdoc.getItemValue("SendTo"));
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", thisdoc.getItemValue("Subject"));
var tempbody:NotesRichtextItem = tempdoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
tempbody.appendText("This is my Mail, click on the doc link below to open the original doc:")
tempbody.addNewLine(2);
tempbody.appendDocLink(thisdoc);
tempdoc.send();
thisdoc.recycle();
tempbody.recycle();
tempdoc.recycle();
```

Result: the button code sends a mail containing a Notes document link to all the recipients that I previously entered in the SendTo field.

If I set the testMail form's property to use the Xpage in Notes (*Defaults >> On Open >> Display Xpage instead >> mailSendTest*), then this also works for the XPinc version. And if the recipient then clicks on the doc link the originating document of course opens in XPinc mode as well.

**Remark:**

I need to save the originating doc at least once otherwise the appended doc link might not be usable for the recipients; could this have been the reason why Fredrik's answer didn't work for you?

Hope this helps. If this is working for you please accept Fredrik's answer.

**Update:**

Changed some variable names in my code example to clarify things

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use only one datasource/form that bounds the xpage? I get the following error: frmDoc ( my datasource ) is undefined?

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing the complete context. In my example above I used exactly one doc datasource which I called maildoc. Unfortunately I used the Same variable Name in my Button code for a different object, Maybe this isndisturbing you; I'll Change my example Code accordingly, hope this helps

Comment: I formulated a new question - I tried your steps , and a new problem occurs ( with Edit Mode / Read Mode for existing docs. ) so I asked a new Question.

Comment: Currently i'm using a single form/ an unique datasource too. ( I thought it is necessarily to use a new form for the mailForm. I modified the code and now I get: Exception occurred calling method NotesRichTextItem.appendDocLink(lotus.domino.local.Document) null - at the appendDoclink line. - the same error I noticed in the Fredrik  suggestion too.

Comment: Please post your Send button's entire code; just put it into your original question marking it as an update; otherwise there's no way to help you

Answer (score 0):

I simply use these two lines:

> var url =
>   @Left(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURL(),"newDocument.xsp")+"newDocument.xsp?documentId="+document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+"&action=openDocument";
>   rtitem.appendText(url);

where newDocument.xsp is the form xsp of the document, rtitem is the rich text field of the mail. That will add the whole link to your document.